# Emplace back fails at in place construction

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, move-constructor, in-place

I have an object that I want to construct exactly once, because the class it is in keeps track its objects by adding raw pointers to them. Constructing it inline seems to fail though:

```
// Defined utilities:
ModuleClusterPlot(Type typeArg, const int& layer, const int& module, const int& ladder, const int& startEventArg, const int& endEventArg);
~ModuleClusterPlot();
// Invalid utilities
ModuleClusterPlot(ModuleClusterPlot& t_other) = delete;
ModuleClusterPlot(ModuleClusterPlot&& t_other) = delete;
ModuleClusterPlot& operator=(const ModuleClusterPlot& t_other) = delete;
ModuleClusterPlot& operator=(ModuleClusterPlot&& t_other) = delete;
```

Calling the constructor via emplace back fails, because it tries to call the move constructor (why?):

```
moduleClusterPlots.emplace_back(t_type, t_layer, t_module, t_ladder, i, i);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am using `gcc 7.1.0` wih `std=c++14` flag.

Minimal example:

```
#include <vector>

class ModuleClusterPlot
{
    public:
        enum Type
        {
            foo = 0,
            bar
        };

        ModuleClusterPlot(Type typeArg);
        ~ModuleClusterPlot();
        // Invalid utilities
        ModuleClusterPlot(ModuleClusterPlot& t_other) = delete;
        ModuleClusterPlot(ModuleClusterPlot&& t_other) = delete;
        ModuleClusterPlot& operator=(const ModuleClusterPlot& t_other) = delete;
        ModuleClusterPlot& operator=(ModuleClusterPlot&& t_other) = delete;

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<ModuleClusterPlot> collection;
    collection.emplace_back(ModuleClusterPlot::foo);
}
```

How can I prevent calling the move constructor here?

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]?

Comment: You write you want to add `raw pointers` but if you get an error message that a copy/move constructor is needed, I guess you are trying to insert an object instead of just the pointer!

Comment: @ThomasSparber I'm adding `this` to the static object holding the pointers.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Ok so please Show the Code and post an MCVE as NathanOliver suggests

Comment: @ThomasSparber I'll do that, my question is more general though, I want to prevent emplace back from calling the move constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Here you are.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Well, as soon as you post real Code we can help you... :-) The error is as I said that you don't emplace/push raw pointers but objects! In that case a move or copy constructor is needed. If you declare `std::vector<ModuleClusterPlot*> collection` it will work

Comment: @ThomasSparber Yes, but this is the construction of the objects. I am calling the normal constructor via `emplace_back` to create an object, but for some reason the move constructor is invoked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::emplace_back` requires a move constructor or copy constructor.  The reason is that it might need to reallocate memory and move/copy the existing objects into a new buffer.

Even though you only called it on an empty vector, which wouldn't actually need to move any existing objects, remember that the same function `emplace_back` can be used on empty and non-empty vectors.  The function can't possibly know it's being used from an empty state only, so when the member function is instantiated, the code to deal with a non-empty vector must be valid too.

Comment: I'll change my container to a linked list then, thank you for actually explaining why it needs move construction!

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the constraints of `emaplce_back`.  If we look at table 101 from [sequence.reqmts] we have

> *Requires*: T shall be EmplaceConstructible into X from args. **For vector, T shall also be MoveInsertable into X.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Since your class is not move insertable it will not work with `emplace_back`.

The reason this is required is because of the `size()` becomes greater than the `capacity()` then the vector needs to allocate new storage and move the elements to that new storage.  If it can't do that then the vector can't function as intended.